# Is it correct to use the English possessive with generic nouns?

Tags: possessives, generic-noun-phrases

I know that a sentence like *"My cat's head is black"* is correct, because the head is that of a specific cat.

But what if I want to write *"I found a lizard's tail under my bed"*?
In this case the tail is not of a specific lizard I'm referring to, it's from a generic lizard.

Is the **'s** after lizard correct, or should I drop it?

What if I want to use this form in a list?

- Cat's head
- Lizard's tail
- Dog's paw

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not ungrammatical to use the possessive in that context, but since you do not have a specific lizard in mind, it would be more idiomatic to say

"I found **a lizard tail** under the bed".

Or

"I found **a bird feather** on the ground".

Concoctions brewed up by witches and warlocks use the periphrastic possessive without article:

> eye of newt
>
> toe of frog

to refer to the *generic* ingredient.

In normal non-concoction circumstances you can say

"I found **the tail of a lizard** under the bed."

Comment: "Concoctions brewed up by witches and warlocks"
Actually I needed for something like this. The coincidences! :)